# Plenty of VS of plenty/a-plenty/aplenty

Tags: difference, usage

There are three different versions of lyrics for the Mermaid song "Part of your world"

- I've got gadgets and gizmos **a-plenty**. I've got **whozits** and **whatzits** galore. You want thingamabobs? I've got twenty! But who cares? No big deal. I want more.
- I've got gadgets and gizmos **of plenty**. I've got **whose-its** and **whats-its** galore. You want thingamabobs? I got twenty. But who cares? No big deal. I want more.
- I've got gadgets and gizmos **aplenty**. I've got **whosits** and **whatsits** galore. You want thingamabobs? I got twenty. But who cares? No big deal. I want more.

The question is, which is correct and is it right to say so?

Notice the other bold words, they seem really strange to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never heard someone use **of plenty** that way. Plenty of things to do is the correct format.

Well songs and poems do not follow a strict  grammar and sentence structure and hence I would suggest you use the standard form unless you are writing a song or poem.